# content of custom icon font in angular is a strange string

Tags: angular, dom, fonts, icons, shadow

I have a problem with my project with a custom icon font from icomoon. Sometimes (really random) in the production build the css of the icon have a strange string included and the most icons look like the one on the right:

[image]

Yeah, the string on the right should be an icon, it also shows this string in the CSS. But funny both icons use the same font and when I investigate the one on the left it shows that it gets overwritten by a shadow dom styling with the right content and also the source is a different style.css:

[image]

After reloading the page the icons are shown normal again.

Comment: I tried ` unicode-range: U+00-FFFF;` but no luck here. It is only appearing since a few weeks so maybe the font got too big, too many glyphs and that's why...

Comment: Ok, I figure out it has something to do with the "optimization" of angular. Without it, it is working fine. I think it removes the `@charset "UTF-8"` when compiling the styles. Does anyone have an idea of how to prevent it or add the charset to the file afterward?